# Switch Workspace using mousewheel Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Tags: mate, workspace-switcher

I am using ubuntu-mate 18.04.

I want to be able to switch across workspaces using mousewheel.
Coming from xfce I'm used to this setting.
I know it can also be done using compiz but I'm currently using Marco as compositor and I prefer to stick with it.

Any suggestion is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have *Workspace Switcher* applet added to the MATE Panel:

[image: Workspace Switcher applet]

Then hover it with mouse cursor and rotate mouse wheel to switch workspaces.

---

Other possibility is to switch window manager to Compiz.
You need to install CompizConfig Settings Manager with

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

then open MATE Tweak and select Compiz on Windows tab:

[image: MATE Tweak]

Then click on *Open CCSM* and change shortcuts for *Desktop Wall* plugin, go to *Bindings* → *Move within wall* and set

- *Move Next* to `<Super>+Button5` (wheel up), confirm disabling *Zoom In button*
- *Move Prev* to `<Super>+Button4` (wheel down), confirm disabling *Zoom Out button*

[image: CCSM]

and enjoy.

Comment: @NOrbert I am aware of _Workspace Switcher_ applet. I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to use the mousewheel anywhere on the desktop to switch workspace, like in XFCE or in Compiz.

Comment: MATE is able to use Compiz. You can setup it as shown in updated answer.

Comment: @NOrbert. I am aware that MATE can use Compiz. As is stated in my initial post I am asking whether this is possible using Marco as compositor.